# Generating CSRF token for Backbone from Django

Tags: django, backbone.js

I've been developing a backbone layer on top of Django and using Django to create the API and having backbone models calling django api to fill in the models. I'm trying to create a login for users using the default django models for users. Since I'm not rendering the pages through django but instead through router in backbone. I can't generate csrf token through django's template language {{ csrf_token }} and thus I can't post any forms.

One way I thought to work around this is to generate the token by having the backbone view fetch from the api endpoint in initialize and have the endpoint generate the token through

```
token = csrf._get_new_csrf_key()
```

and then passing it to backbone frontend through json then following the django documentation

```
var csrftoken = "<%=obj.csrftoken%>";

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

This didn't work since I still get Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simplest workaround is to read the `csrftoken` cookie and pass it to django via as `X-CSRFToken` header. This [section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax) in the Django docs should give you the correct example:

Comment: I've followed the django docs exactly in setting up the header as the code is exactly the same as the example in the doc.